# Using variables in system() function c++

Tags: windows, curl, system, c++

```
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("aaa.txt");
  getline (myfile,line);
  system("curl.exe -b cookie.txt -d test="+line+"  http://example.com");
```

And It doesn't work! I also tried line.c_str(); But it didnt work either. Please help me.

Comment: Downvoted because passing variables to `system()` is **actively dangerous**. Use `spawn()` on Win32, `fork()/exec()` or `posix_spawn()` on *nix.

Comment: @ninjalj the security of the system has nothing to do with the question. Every time there is a SO question having to do with system(), someone has to comment on security and sometimes people (like you) downvote it. It contributes nothing and only clutters the page. The question was "how" to use system(), not a question on the best ways to use it. "Use something else instead" is not a useful comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're passing a C++ string to a C function system(). c_str() can help, but you should apply it to the whole string:

```
system(("curl.exe -b cookie.txt -d test="+line+"  http://example.com").c_str());
```

As noted in the comments below, passing random variables to system() can be quite dangerous, so you should only do that if you know exactly what it may contain. If it's supplied by the user or received from the network, you probably shouldn't do that. Pass the string through some sort of "escape" function or use spawn()/exec()/whatever else that doesn't pass it to the shell.

Comment: I find it cleaner to add an `int system(std::string const& s) { return s.c_str(); }` overload.

Comment: @MSalters, did you mean `int system(std::string const& s) {return system(s.c_str());}`? Yes, it looks like a good idea.

Comment: @ninjalj, the question was about _how_ to use variables in such call, not whether it's dangerous or not. In fact, sine the guy reads the variable from a file, not directly from user or network, it isn't necessarily dangerous. That depends on where he got this file. If it's a temporary file generated by the same application and it isn't accessible externally, I guess it's fine. Although I agree that I should have mentioned possible dangers.

Comment: And now that you've clearly warned about the dangers of system(), I've removed the downvote. Right now, this question has ~350 views, we don't want SO to become a resource on bad practices.

Answer (score 11):

**Problem 1:**

Your problem stems from the fact that `system` is of signature:

```
int system (const char *command);
```

What you have is of type `std::string`.

One way to fix this is to build a new `std::string` and then get the char pointer using `c_str()`.

```
string cmd("curl.exe -b cookie.txt -d test=");
cmd += line;
cmd += "  http://example.com";
```

Then pass the content to `system`.

```
system(cmd.c_str());
```

**Problem 2:**

Reading data and passing it unvalidated and unclean to `system` will allow anyone using your program to run commands at the shell.

This is a security risk.

Comment: Aren't `system` cals the same as typing the command in cmd.exe?

Comment: @Xeo: Yup and if you passed `foo & fire_nukes.exe & REM` to his program it would run curl.exe then attempt to run fire_nukes.exe. It would look slightly different on *nix, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Build the string you're passing to `system()` with a stringstream!

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("aaa.txt");
    getline(myfile,line);
    stringstream call_line;
    call_line << "curl.exe -b cookie.txt -d test=" << line << "  http://example.com");
    system(call_line.str().c_str());
}
```

Comment: @ninjalj: So, we know that using `system()` is dangerous if you allow arbitary user input. This doesn't change the fact that the OP wanted to assembly input from a file. What if the file is protected against user access? What if it actually reads from a database or something? We don't know and we don't care, the security is part of the OP's responsibility. This is not a reason for a downvote. I could remove the `system()` call and only show string assembling. What now?

Comment: you could tell the OP to use an API where each argument is separate, and doesn't use an underlying shell to parse the command line.