# How can I escape variables sent to the 'system' command in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, escaping

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907805/using-variables-in-system-function-c) talks about using the `system` command and passing variables. Here is an example it gives:

```
string cmd("curl -b cookie.txt -d test=");
cmd += line;
cmd += "  http://example.com";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

One of the comments mentions that if `line` was passed and contained `foo & fire_nukes.exe & REM` then it's quite possible something bad could happen.

PHP has a great function called `escape_shell_args` which can be used to escape parameters that are being passed to the program. Does C++ have a way to do that?

Comment: You could always use `fork` and `exec`...

Comment: `man fork`, `man exec` :-) (You can't really say "I'm using Linux" in earnest if you don't know `man`!)

Comment: `man 3 exec`. Or maybe for you: `man man`...?

Comment: And you probably should use the libcurl from C http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: @KerrekSB No you shouldn’t! Not everyone uses Linux! `system` is part of `<cstdlib>` but there is no platform independent fork, exec (AFAIK). I know `system` is evil, but it’s the evil you know, …and actually exists on Windows (without cygwin).

Comment: @StevenSpark: But the question is tagged "linux"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is not to use `system()` at all. Use `fork()` and `exec()` and friends.
Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int fork_curl(char *line)
{
    std::string linearg("line=");
    linearg += line;

    int pid = fork();
    if(pid != 0) {
        /* We're in the parent process, return the child's pid. */
        return pid;
    }
    /* Otherwise, we're in the child process, so let's exec curl. */

    execlp("curl", "-b", "cookie.txt", "-d", linearg.c_str());  
    /* exec is not supposed to return, so something
       must have gone wrong. */
    exit(100);
    /* Note: You should probably use an exit  status
       that doesn't collide with these used by curl, if possible. */
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int cpid = fork_curl("test");
    if(cpid == -1) {
        /* Failed to fork */
        error(1, errno, "Fork failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Optionally, wait for the child to exit and get
       the exit status. */
    int status;
    waitpid(cpid, &status, 0);
    if(! WIFEXITED(status)) {
        error(1, 0, "The child was killed or segfaulted or something\n");
    }

    status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    /* Status now contains the exit status of the child process. */
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of those commands I should be using? Or possibly give an example of how to use those commands?

Comment: an example *would* be nice :)

Comment: @SteveBrown I've added an example.

Comment: NOOOOOO! execl replaces the current process and fork() is really badly defined on some platforms. Really NOOO!

Comment: However, it seems that if the command is a shell script (with #!/bin/bash and chmod 777) you still must escape the arguments, otherwise you get /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 4):

Never pass user input into a `system` call. Ever.

You can try to escape all the characters that you think are dangerous, but you will get it wrong.

Instead, go at it from the other direction: let the user provide any of a selection of inputs that *you* define, then do a `switch` and build your own system call from scratch.

Admittedly this gets a little tricky when the input to the command-line application to invoke is freeform but, well, that's what actual libraries are for. `libcurl`, anyone?

Comment: What if you need to pass the variables that were passed to your program to another program? Perhaps a file path? This is what I'm attempting to do. The reason I haven't done it yet is because I know it's not "safe" and so I'd like to figure out what a safe(er) way to do it would be. thanks.

Comment: You mean a call to system(3), not a syscall as in syscalls(2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try execl..

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execvp.htm

```
#include <unistd.h> 

int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
```

Comment: Maybe this is what I need. If I want pass the variables that were passed to my program to the `/bin/echo` command, how would I do that? (Pointless but let's use it as an example)

Comment: You should define what *variables* mean for you. Once you understood well in your head what they mean, you nearly solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See the man page listing all [syscalls](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) (system calls are not the `system(3)` function which forks a shell).

Read more about [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) and [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), and the overall organization of [operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)

Back to your question, you could quote for the shell (just follow the shell escape rules to transform your strings; for example prefix any non-letter character with a backslash).

See also the man pages of [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), etc.

Read a good book on [advanced linux programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and the famous [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/)

Use the freedom of most of the software on a Linux distribution. For example, you could study the source code of a simple shell like `sash`.

And perhaps you just want to use curl. Then the best way is to **code for the [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library** (without any call to  `system(3)`)

Have fun learning all this!

Comment: The problem is that even escaping every non-letter is not enough. What if a malicious user launches a setuid program with a modified PATH and/or IFS?

Comment: I agree, but at least it answer the question. My feeling is that the poster should not use `system` nor fork a `curl` process but learn to call the functions from `libcurl`

Comment: And the rest of your answer is quite good. But, really, `system()` is really dangerous.

Comment: Yes, I agree that using `system` is the wrong way. And I do know it is dangerous. But it is what the original poster imagines he want. (My point is that he just have to learn about libcurl).

Comment: Your first two paragraphs are not relevant to the question; calls to `system()` and system calls are very different things.

Comment: I know that. I was suggesting to avoid `system(3)` and use only system calls. Actually, the original poster just need to learn how to call `libcurl` and avoid all the mess....

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to safely pass parameters to the comand executed by `system(3)`

```
setenv ("mypar1", "'$(rm -rf /)", 1);
setenv ("mypar2", "\"; rm -rf /", 1);
system ("echo mypar1=\"$mypar1\" mypar2=\"$mypar2\");
```

Neither of these evil codes will be executed, simply printed.