# pipe inside (awk) System command in cpp

Tags: c++, string, awk, pipeline

I have the awk command wch I want to wrap in system().

```
std::string cmd = "awk -F\|  '{ var1=$2; var2=$5; print var1, var2 }' 1.txt";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Getting the error as,

> error: unknown escape sequence '\|'

I have tried giving the quotes in different way. But, nothing helps.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539243/how-can-i-escape-variables-sent-to-the-system-command-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the `\`:

```
std::string cmd = "awk -F\\|  '{ var1=$2; var2=$5; print var1, var2 }' 1.txt";
//-----------------------^
```

When you create your C++ string, `\` is treated as an escape character, unless you escape it.

Alternatively in this case, you could just quote the delimiter, avoiding the need to escape it:

```
std::string cmd = "awk -F'|'  '{ print $2, $5 }' 1.txt";
```

I assume that your script may be more complex that this in reality but I simplified it for you anyway, in case that helps.

A final option, using raw string literals (which are supported in C++11):

```
std::string cmd = R"awk -F\|  '{ print $2, $5 }' 1.txt";
```

The `R` prefix means that the `\` is no longer interpreted as an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

maybe scaping the -F"|" quotes??

```
std::string cmd = "awk -F\"|\" '{ var1=$2; var2=$5; print var1, var2 }' 1.txt";
system(cmd.c_str());
```